# Javacard applet to subtract two hexadecimal array of byte

Tags: javacard

I'm try to write a javacard applet that need to add/sub two array of bytes.
the addition was success but the subtraction fail in some cases ("when there is a borrow from the procceding byte").

Can you check my code and improve it to work better?

```
package phase1;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.Util;
import javacard.security.CryptoException;


public class keygen extends Applet {
    public static final short _0 = 0;

    public final static byte[] one = {(byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff,(byte) 0xff,(byte) 0xff,(byte) 0xff};
    byte [] G = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x11};

    private keygen() {

    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)throws ISOException  {
        try{
            new keygen().register();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x8888);
        }
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (selectingApplet()) return;

        //short sendlen = 0;
        byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer();
        byte ins = buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS];
        byte [] val = new byte [(short) G.length];
        short i;
        short len = (short) G.length ;
        short Alen = (short) (len - 1);
        short b = (short) 0 ;
        byte[] Z = new byte [(short) len];
        byte[] y = new byte [(short) 2];
        try{
        switch (ins){
        case (byte) 0x01: //0x0F
        {   
            Z = addarray (G , one);

            apdu.setOutgoing();
            buf = Z;
            apdu.setOutgoingLength(len);
            apdu.sendBytesLong(Z, (short) 0,len);
            break;
        }
        case (byte) 0x02: //0x0F
        {   //Z = new byte [(short) 7];
            Z = subarray1 (G , one);
            apdu.setOutgoing();
            buf= Z;
            apdu.setOutgoingLength(len);
            apdu.sendBytesLong(Z, (short) 0,len);
            break;
        }
        default:
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }
        }catch (CryptoException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt(((CryptoException) e).getReason());
        }
    }

    private byte [] addarray (byte [] Arr1, byte [] Arr2 )
    {
        short i;
        short [] X = new short [(short) 6];
        short len = (short) Arr1.length ;
        short Alen = (short) (len - 1);
        byte [] AddArr = new byte [len];
        short R = (short) 0;
        byte[] Z = new byte [(short) 2];

        for (i = Alen; i >= 0 ;  i--)
        {                       
            X[i] =   (short) ((Arr1[i] & 0xFF) + (Arr2[i]&0xff) + R);
            Util.setShort(Z, (short) 0, (short) X[i]);
            AddArr[i] = (byte) Z[1];
            R = (short) (Z[0]);
        }

        return AddArr;
    }

    private byte [] subarray1 (byte [] Arr1, byte [] Arr2)
    {
        short i;
        byte [] X = new byte [(short) 6];
        short len = (short) Arr1.length ;
        short Alen = (short) (len - 1);
        byte [] SubArr = new byte [len];
        short R = (short) 0;
        byte[] Z = new byte [(short) 2];

        for (i = Alen; i > 0 ;  i--)
        {
            X[i] =   (byte) (Arr1[i]  - Arr2[i]  - (byte) R );
            Util.setShort(Z, (short) 0, (short) X[i]);
            SubArr[i] = (byte) Z[1];
            R = (short) (Z[0] );

        }
        return SubArr;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hexadecimals is a way to view bytes; they *represent* the bytes in a human readable way (well, somewhat readable anyways). Bytes themselves are binary, they consist of 8 octets although they are generally indivisible in most computers (you cannot store half a byte without requiring a full byte). You subtract integers represented by the byte arrays.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36966764/5128464) includes some implementation of subtraction for java card.

Answer (score 1):

There is an optional class in Java Card API named `bigIntNumber`. If your card doesn't implemented it, I share its source code with you:

```
/**
 * Class BigIntNumber provides addition, subtraction and comparison functions
 * for unsigned integers represented in byte array format in bug endian order.
 *
 */
public class BigIntNumber {

    /**
     * Add two unsigned integers represented in array A and B. The sum stored in
     * array C
     *
     * @param A the left operand
     * @param AOff the starting position in array A.
     * @param B the right operand.
     * @param BOff the starting position in array B.
     * @param C the result of (A+B)
     * @param COff the starting position in array C.
     * @param len the number of bytes in the operands as well in the computed
     * result. this parameter can not be a negative number.
     * @return false if the result overflows. if overflows occurs, the sum would
     * be the true mathematical result with the most significant bytes discarded
     * to fit into array C of the specified length.
     * @throws ArrayOuutOfBoundException if  array access out of bound.
     */
    public static boolean add(byte[] A, byte AOff, byte[] B, byte BOff, byte[] C, byte COff, byte len) {
        short result = 0;

        for (len = (byte) (len - 1); len >= 0; len--) {
            // add two unsigned bytes and the carry from the
            // previous byte computation.
            result = (short) (getUnsignedByte(A, AOff, len) + getUnsignedByte(B, BOff, len) + result);
            // store the result in byte array C
            C[(byte) (len + COff)] = (byte) result;
            // has a carry?
            if (result > 0x00FF) {
                result = 1;
                result = (short) (result + 0x100);
            } else {
                result = 0;
            }
        }
        //produce overflow in the sum.
        if (result == 1) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }


     /**
     * Subtract two unsigned integers represented in array A and B. The sum stored in
     * array C
     *
     * @param A the left operand
     * @param AOff the starting position in array A.
     * @param B the right operand.
     * @param BOff the starting position in array B.
     * @param C the result of (A-B)
     * @param COff the starting position in array C.
     * @param len the number of bytes in the operands as well in the computed
     * result. this parameter can not be a negative number.
     * @return false if the result underflows. if underflows occurs, the sum would
     * be the mathematical result of A + ~B + 1.
     * @throws ArrayOuutOfBoundException if  array access out of bound.
     */
    public static boolean subtract(byte[] A, byte AOff, byte[] B, byte BOff, byte[] C, byte COff, byte len) {
        byte borrow = 0;
        short result;

        for (len = (byte) (len - 1); len >= 0; len--) {
            // subtract one unsigned byte from the other.
            // also subtract the borrow from the previous byte computation.
            result = (short) (getUnsignedByte(A, AOff, len) - getUnsignedByte(B, BOff, len) - borrow);
            // need to borrow?
            if (result < 0) {
                borrow = 1;
                result = (short) (result + 0x100);
            } else {
                borrow = 0;
            }
            // store the result in C
            C[(byte) (len + COff)] = (byte) result;
        }
        // is the result underflow?
        if (borrow == 1) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }



     /**
     * Compare two unsigned integers represented in array A and B. The sum stored in
     * array C
     *
     * @param A the left operand
     * @param AOff the starting position in array A.
     * @param B the right operand.
     * @param BOff the starting position in array B.
     * @param C the result of (A-B)
     * @param COff the starting position in array C.
     * @param len the number of bytes in the operands as well in the computed
     * result. this parameter can not be a negative number.
     * @return the result of comparison as below:
     * 0 if identical
     * 1 if the left operand is bigger than the right operand
     * -1 if the left operand is smaller than the right operand
     * @throws ArrayOuutOfBoundException if  array access out of bound.
     */
    public static byte compare(byte[] A, byte AOff, byte[] B, byte BOff, byte len) {
        byte count = (byte) 0;

        for (; count < len; count++) {
            short C = getUnsignedByte(A, AOff, count);
            short D = getUnsignedByte(A, AOff, count);

            if (C < D) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (C > D) {
                return 1;
            }

        }
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     *
     * Get the unsigned byte at the index (AOff + count)
     */
    private static short getUnsignedByte(byte[] A, byte AOff, byte count) {
        return (short) (A[(short) (count + AOff)] & 0x00FF);
    }

}
```

And this is a sample applet that I wroto to show you how does the above class methods work:

```
package phase1;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.Util;
import static phase1.BigIntNumber.*;

public class TestBigInt extends Applet {

    // Defining global arrays for Operands A and B.
    // LenA and LenB are defined to check if equal length of A and B are going
    // to add, compare or subtract or not. Len of operands musb be equal between 1 byte to 8 bytes.
    public static byte[] OpA = new byte[8];
    public static byte[] OpB = new byte[8];
    public static byte[] result = new byte[8];

    public static byte lenA;
    public static byte lenB;

    // Defining supported INS valuse for APDU Command.
    public static final byte INS_INIT_OPERAND = (byte) 0x10;
    public static final byte INS_ADD = (byte) 0x20;
    public static final byte INS_SUBTRACT = (byte) 0x30;
    public static final byte INS_COMPARE = (byte) 0x40;

    // P1 parameter in the APDU command
    public static final byte OPERAND_A = 0x01;
    public static final byte OPERAND_B = 0x02;

    // Defining Exception Status Words
    public static short SW_NOT_EQUAL_LENGTH = (short) 0x6910;
    public static short SW_OVERFLOW_OCCURS = (short) 0x6911;
    public static short SW_UNDERFLOW_OCCURS = (short) 0x6912;

    private TestBigInt() {

    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength) throws ISOException {
        new TestBigInt().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }
        byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer();

        switch (buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {
            case INS_INIT_OPERAND:
                apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
                if (buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] > (byte) 0x08) {
                    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_LENGTH);
                }
                if (buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] == OPERAND_A) {
                    Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buf, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, OpA, (short) 0x00, buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC]);
                    lenA = buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC];
                } else if (buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] == OPERAND_B) {
                    Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buf, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, OpB, (short) 0x00, buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC]);
                    lenB = buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC];
                } else {
                    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_P1P2);
                }
                break;

            case INS_ADD:
                if (lenA != lenB) {
                    ISOException.throwIt(SW_NOT_EQUAL_LENGTH);
                }
                if (add(OpA, (byte) 0x00, OpB, (byte) 0x00, result, (byte) 0x00, lenA)) {
                    apdu.sendBytesLong(result, (short) 0x00, (short) lenA);
                } else {
                    ISOException.throwIt(SW_OVERFLOW_OCCURS);
                }
                break;
            case INS_SUBTRACT:
                if (lenA != lenB) {
                    ISOException.throwIt(SW_NOT_EQUAL_LENGTH);
                }
                if (subtract(OpA, (byte) 0x00, OpB, (byte) 0x00, result, (byte) 0x00, lenA)) {
                    apdu.sendBytesLong(result, (short) 0x00, (short) lenA);
                } else {
                    ISOException.throwIt(SW_UNDERFLOW_OCCURS);
                }
                break;
            case INS_COMPARE:
                // ... 
                break;
            default:
                ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }

    }

}
```

It seems works fine:

```
Connect successful.
Download Cap begin...
Download Cap successful.
Install Applet begin...
Install Applet successful.
Select Applet begin...
Select Applet successful.
Send: 00 10 01 00 07 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 00 //Initilizing Operand A
Recv: 90 00
Time used: 21.000 ms
Send: 00 10 02 00 07 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 00 //Initlizing Operand B
Recv: 90 00
Time used: 19.000 ms
Send: 00 20 00 00 00 // Compute A+B
Recv: 22 44 66 88 AA CC EE 90 00
Time used: 67.000 ms
Send: 00 30 00 00 00 // Compute A-B
Recv: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00
Time used: 73.000 ms
Send: 00 10 02 00 07 00 00 44 44 44 44 44 00 // Changing Operand B
Recv: 90 00
Time used: 14.000 ms
Send: 00 20 00 00 00 // Compute A+B again
Recv: 11 22 77 88 99 AA BB 90 00
Time used: 66.000 ms
Send: 00 30 00 00 00 // Compute A-B
Recv: 11 21 EF 00 11 22 33 90 00
Time used: 71.000 ms
```

Sorry, I didn't checked your code. Just two simple hint:

1- Try to don't use dynamic fields in methods. Java Card doesn't support automatic garbage collection, so the memory that you assign to a field dynamically (i.e. using `new` keyword), will not reclaimed automatically until calling `requestObjectDeletion()` method (and it's optional too!) :)

2- `0x8888` is not a standard status world in the ISO7816-4 standard and some smart cards has problem with non-standard status words. Try to choose `6XXX` (`60XX` is also non-standard value) or `9XXX` for status words.

Comment: thanks for your response but I'm not understand your second comment can you clarify it more. By the way I try to use your code but it is not working with me can you help me in solving its problem. I got 6F00 error.

Comment: @amjadal-amr For the second comment: You catch the exceptions in the `install()` method and use `0x8888`value as status word for `isoException.throwIt(0x8888)`. Well, based on ISO7816 Standard, the legal values for status words are 0x6XXX (like : 0x6112, 0x6389, etc) and 0x9XXX (like 0x9998, 0x9567, etc). _0x60XX format is not legal too_.

Comment: @amjadal-amr When you receive `0x6F00`? Please add the commands you sent.

Comment: I receive it in the add and subtract case. I use the GPShell script to do that (send_apdu -APDU 0020000000
send_apdu -APDU 0030000000)

Comment: @amjadal-amr Did you changed anything in above classes? It works fine for me.

Comment: in the BigIntNumber class > compare -> short D = getUnsignedByte(B, BOff, count); @Abraham