# Using RSA for modulo-multiplication leads to error on Java Card

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, javacard

Hello I'm working on a project on Java Card which implies a lot of modulo-multiplication. I managed to implement an modulo-multiplication on this platform using RSA cryptosystem but it seems to work for certain numbers.

```
public byte[] modMultiply(byte[] x, short xOffset, short xLength, byte[] y,
        short yOffset, short yLength, short tempOutoffset) {

    //copy x value to temporary rambuffer
    Util.arrayCopy(x, xOffset, tempBuffer, tempOutoffset, xLength);


    // copy the y value to match th size of rsa_object
    Util.arrayFillNonAtomic(eempromTempBuffer, (short)0, (byte) (Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS-1),(byte)0x00);
    Util.arrayCopy(y,yOffset,eempromTempBuffer,(short)(Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS - yLength),yLength);

    // x+y
    if (JBigInteger.add(x,xOffset,xLength, eempromTempBuffer,
            (short)0,Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS)) ;
    if(this.isGreater(x, xOffset, xLength, tempBuffer,Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS)>0)
    {
        JBigInteger.subtract(x,xOffset,xLength, tempBuffer,
                Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS);
    }

    //(x+y)2
    mRsaCipherForSquaring.init(mRsaPublicKekForSquare, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);

    mRsaCipherForSquaring.doFinal(x, xOffset, Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS, x,
            xOffset); // OK

    mRsaCipherForSquaring.doFinal(tempBuffer, tempOutoffset, Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS, tempBuffer, tempOutoffset); // OK


    if (JBigInteger.subtract(x, xOffset, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS, tempBuffer, tempOutoffset,
            Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS)) {
        JBigInteger.add(x, xOffset, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS, tempBuffer,
                Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS);
    } 

    mRsaCipherForSquaring.doFinal(eempromTempBuffer, yOffset, Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS, eempromTempBuffer, yOffset); //OK 


    if (JBigInteger.subtract(x, xOffset, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS, eempromTempBuffer, yOffset,
            Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS)) {

        JBigInteger.add(x, xOffset, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS, tempBuffer,
                Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS);

    }
    // ((x+y)^2 - x^2 -y^2)/2
    JBigInteger.modular_division_by_2(x, xOffset,Configuration. LENGTH_MODULUS, tempBuffer, Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS);
    return x;
}


public static boolean add(byte[] x, short xOffset, short xLength, byte[] y,
        short yOffset, short yLength) {
    short digit_mask = 0xff;
    short digit_len = 0x08;
    short result = 0;
    short i = (short) (xLength + xOffset - 1);
    short j = (short) (yLength + yOffset - 1);

    for (; i >= xOffset; i--, j--) {
        result = (short) (result + (short) (x[i] & digit_mask) + (short) (y[j] & digit_mask));

        x[i] = (byte) (result & digit_mask);
        result = (short) ((result >> digit_len) & digit_mask);
    }
    while (result > 0 && i >= xOffset) {
        result = (short) (result + (short) (x[i] & digit_mask));
        x[i] = (byte) (result & digit_mask);
        result = (short) ((result >> digit_len) & digit_mask);
        i--;
    }

    return result != 0;
}
public static boolean subtract(byte[] x, short xOffset, short xLength, byte[] y,
        short yOffset, short yLength) {
    short digit_mask = 0xff;
    short i = (short) (xLength + xOffset - 1);
    short j = (short) (yLength + yOffset - 1);
    short carry = 0;
    short subtraction_result = 0;

    for (; i >= xOffset && j >= yOffset; i--, j--) {
        subtraction_result = (short) ((x[i] & digit_mask)
                - (y[j] & digit_mask) - carry);
        x[i] = (byte) (subtraction_result & digit_mask);
        carry = (short) (subtraction_result < 0 ? 1 : 0);
    }
    for (; i >= xOffset && carry > 0; i--) {
        if (x[i] != 0)
            carry = 0;
        x[i] -= 1;
    }

    return carry > 0;
}



 public short isGreater(byte[] x,short xOffset,short xLength,byte[] y ,short yOffset,short yLength)
    {
        if(xLength > yLength)
            return (short)1;
        if(xLength < yLength)
            return (short)(-1);
        short digit_mask = 0xff;
        short digit_len = 0x08;
        short result = 0;
        short i = (short) (xLength + xOffset - 1);
        short j = (short) (yLength + yOffset - 1);

        for (; i >= xOffset; i--, j--) {
            result = (short) (result + (short) (x[i] & digit_mask) - (short) (y[j] & digit_mask));
            if(result > 0)
                return (short)1;
            if(result < 0)
                return (short)-1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The code works well for little number but fails on bigger one

Comment: Throw (short) (0x6A00 | getReason()) instead...

Comment: @vojta Now i get (Unknown ISO7816 error : 0x6A05)

Comment: @vojta It seems to me that after `if (JBigInteger.add(x,xOffset,xLength, eempromTempBuffer,
            (short)0,Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS)) {
        JBigInteger.subtract(x,xOffset,xLength, tempBuffer,
                Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS);
    } ` the value of `x` is greater than the modulus and the RSA fails.

Comment: Then conditional normalizing via modulus subtraction might help, i.e. if/while input value is greater than modulus then subtract modulus from the value. Might be acceptably cheap as well. Tracing in a [simulator](https://jcardsim.org/) might help -- you can watch the intermediate values here.

Comment: @vlp the link doesn't work.I managed not the get the error by subtracting the modulus value but I don''t get the expected value

Comment: Strange, it works for me. What about [this](http://jcardsim.org/)? Or google for jcardsim.

Comment: @vlp Thanks  but it's stil hard for me tu debug the multiplication.For little numbers it works perfectly but on bigger ( 128 bytes ) I don't get the expected output.

Comment: Is your comparison code correct (beware that `Util.arrayCompare()` can't be used as it compares individual bytes as signed)?

Comment: @vlp I will update the code with the modifications

Comment: Please, post the complete code of your applet.

Comment: @vojta It part of a full project.If you're interested I could send you an email.I gueas that the problem is the wrong reduction on (a+b)^2 mod p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by changing the mathematical formula of multiplication.I posted below the updated code.

```
private byte[] multiply(byte[] x, short xOffset, short xLength, byte[] y,
        short yOffset, short yLength,short tempOutoffset)
{
    normalize();
    //copy x value to temporary rambuffer
    Util.arrayFillNonAtomic(tempBuffer, tempOutoffset,(short) (Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS+tempOutoffset),(byte)0x00);
    Util.arrayCopy(x, xOffset, tempBuffer, (short)(Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS - xLength), xLength);

    // copy the y value to match th size of rsa_object
    Util.arrayFillNonAtomic(ram_y, IConsts.OFFSET_START, (short) (Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS-1),(byte)0x00);
    Util.arrayCopy(y,yOffset,ram_y,(short)(Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS - yLength),yLength);

    Util.arrayFillNonAtomic(ram_y_prime, IConsts.OFFSET_START, (short) (Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS-1),(byte)0x00);
    Util.arrayCopy(y,yOffset,ram_y_prime,(short)(Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS - yLength),yLength);

    Util.arrayFillNonAtomic(ram_x, IConsts.OFFSET_START, (short) (Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS-1),(byte)0x00);
    Util.arrayCopy(x,xOffset,ram_x,(short)(Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS - xLength),xLength);

    // if x>y
    if(this.isGreater(ram_x, IConsts.OFFSET_START, Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS, ram_y,IConsts.OFFSET_START, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS)>0)
    {

        // x <- x-y
        JBigInteger.subtract(ram_x,IConsts.OFFSET_START,Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS, ram_y,
                IConsts.OFFSET_START, Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS);
    }
    else
    {

        // y <- y-x
        JBigInteger.subtract(ram_y_prime,IConsts.OFFSET_START,Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS, ram_x,
                IConsts.OFFSET_START, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS);
         // ramy stores the (y-x) values copy value to ram_x
        Util.arrayCopy(ram_y_prime, IConsts.OFFSET_START,ram_x,IConsts.OFFSET_START,Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS);

    }

        //|x-y|2
        mRsaCipherForSquaring.init(mRsaPublicKekForSquare, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
        mRsaCipherForSquaring.doFinal(ram_x, IConsts.OFFSET_START, Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS, ram_x,
                IConsts.OFFSET_START); // OK

        // x^2
        mRsaCipherForSquaring.doFinal(tempBuffer, tempOutoffset, Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS, tempBuffer, tempOutoffset); // OK

        // y^2
        mRsaCipherForSquaring.doFinal(ram_y,IConsts.OFFSET_START, Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS, ram_y,IConsts.OFFSET_START); //OK 



        if (JBigInteger.add(ram_y, IConsts.OFFSET_START, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS, tempBuffer, tempOutoffset,
                Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS)) {
              // y^2 + x^2 
            JBigInteger.subtract(ram_y, IConsts.OFFSET_START, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS, tempBuffer,
                    Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS);
        } 


        //  x^2 + y^2
        if (JBigInteger.subtract(ram_y, IConsts.OFFSET_START, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS, ram_x, IConsts.OFFSET_START,
                Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS)) {

            JBigInteger.add(ram_y, IConsts.OFFSET_START, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS, tempBuffer,
                    Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS);
    }
    // (x^2 + y^2 - (x-y)^2)/2
   JBigInteger.modular_division_by_2(ram_y, IConsts.OFFSET_START,Configuration. LENGTH_MODULUS, tempBuffer, Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS);
   return ram_y;
}
```

The problem was that for some numbers for same numbers `a` and `b` on 1024 bits the sum `a+b` overcome the value `p` of the modulus.In above code I subtract from `a+b` the  `p` value in order to make the RSA functioning.But this thing is not mathematically correct because `(a+b)^2 mod p` is different from `((a+b) mod p)^2 mod p` . By changing the formula from  `((x+y)^2 -x^2 -y^2)/2` to `(x^2 + y^2 - (x-y)^2)/2` I was sure I will never have overflow because `a-b` is smaller than `p`. Based on [link above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966764/using-rsa-for-modulo-multiplication-leads-to-error-on-java-card) I changed the code moving all the operations in RAM.

Comment: (Unfortunately) running a test shows that your code fails on `(14716 * 44186) mod 49253` (while testing this I used working `isGreater()` and had to correct the 3rd argument of the `Util.arrayFillNonAtomic()` call during the "copy x value to temporary rambuffer" part -- you probably do not want to add `tempOutoffset` here). Just wanted to tell you...good luck! PS: [this](https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/395143113437/dissertacao.pdf)(section 4.2.3) and [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178424/modulus-distributing-over-multiplication) might be interesting for you

Answer (score 1):

Below is a very simple unit test with a (hopefully) working variant of your code:

```
package test.java.so;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

import javacard.framework.JCSystem;
import javacard.framework.Util;
import javacard.security.KeyBuilder;
import javacard.security.RSAPublicKey;
import javacardx.crypto.Cipher;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import sutil.test.AbstractTest;

public class So36966764_Test extends AbstractTest {

    private static final int NUM_BITS = 1024;

    // Dummy
    static class Configuration {
        public static final short LENGTH_MODULUS = NUM_BITS/8;
        public static final short LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS = LENGTH_MODULUS;
        public static final short TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS = 0;
        public static final short TEMP_OFFSET_RESULT = LENGTH_MODULUS;
    }

    private byte[] tempBuffer = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short)(Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_RESULT+Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS), JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
    private byte[] eempromTempBuffer = new byte[Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS]; // Why EEPROM?
    private RSAPublicKey mRsaPublicKekForSquare = (RSAPublicKey)KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_RSA_PUBLIC, (short)NUM_BITS, false);
    private Cipher mRsaCipherForSquaring = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_RSA_NOPAD, false);

    // Assuming xLength==yLength==LENGTH_MODULUS
    public byte[] modMultiply(byte[] x, short xOffset, short xLength, byte[] y, short yOffset, short yLength, short tempOutoffset) {

        //copy x value to temporary rambuffer
        Util.arrayCopy(x, xOffset, tempBuffer, tempOutoffset, xLength);

        // copy the y value to match th size of rsa_object
        Util.arrayFillNonAtomic(eempromTempBuffer, (short)0, (short) (Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS-1),(byte)0x00);
        Util.arrayCopy(y,yOffset,eempromTempBuffer,(short)(Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS - yLength),yLength);

        // x+y
        if(add(x,xOffset,xLength, eempromTempBuffer, (short)0,Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS)) {
            subtract(x,xOffset,xLength, tempBuffer, Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS);
        }
        while(isGreater(x, xOffset, xLength, tempBuffer,Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS)>0) {
            subtract(x,xOffset,xLength, tempBuffer,Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS);
        }

        //(x+y)2
        mRsaCipherForSquaring.init(mRsaPublicKekForSquare, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
        mRsaCipherForSquaring.doFinal(x, xOffset, Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS, x, xOffset); // OK

        mRsaCipherForSquaring.doFinal(tempBuffer, tempOutoffset, Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS, tempBuffer, tempOutoffset); // OK

        if (subtract(x, xOffset, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS, tempBuffer, tempOutoffset,
                Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS)) {
            add(x, xOffset, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS, tempBuffer,
                    Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS);
        }

        /*WRONG OFFSET mRsaCipherForSquaring.doFinal(eempromTempBuffer, yOffset, Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS, eempromTempBuffer, yOffset); */
        mRsaCipherForSquaring.doFinal(eempromTempBuffer, (short)0, Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS, eempromTempBuffer, (short)0); //OK

        /*WRONG OFFSET if (subtract(x, xOffset, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS, eempromTempBuffer, yOffset,*/
        if (subtract(x, xOffset, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS, eempromTempBuffer, (short)0,Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS)) {
            add(x, xOffset, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS, tempBuffer,
                    Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS);
        }
        // ((x+y)^2 - x^2 -y^2)/2
        modular_division_by_2(x, xOffset,Configuration. LENGTH_MODULUS, tempBuffer, Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS);
        return x;
    }

    public static boolean add(byte[] x, short xOffset, short xLength, byte[] y, short yOffset, short yLength) {
        short digit_mask = 0xff;
        short digit_len = 0x08;
        short result = 0;
        short i = (short) (xLength + xOffset - 1);
        short j = (short) (yLength + yOffset - 1);

        for (; i >= xOffset; i--, j--) {
            result = (short) (result + (short) (x[i] & digit_mask) + (short) (y[j] & digit_mask));

            x[i] = (byte) (result & digit_mask);
            result = (short) ((result >> digit_len) & digit_mask);
        }
        while (result > 0 && i >= xOffset) {
            result = (short) (result + (short) (x[i] & digit_mask));
            x[i] = (byte) (result & digit_mask);
            result = (short) ((result >> digit_len) & digit_mask);
            i--;
        }

        return result != 0;
    }

    public static boolean subtract(byte[] x, short xOffset, short xLength, byte[] y, short yOffset, short yLength) {
        short digit_mask = 0xff;
        short i = (short) (xLength + xOffset - 1);
        short j = (short) (yLength + yOffset - 1);
        short carry = 0;
        short subtraction_result = 0;

        for (; i >= xOffset && j >= yOffset; i--, j--) {
            subtraction_result = (short) ((x[i] & digit_mask)
                    - (y[j] & digit_mask) - carry);
            x[i] = (byte) (subtraction_result & digit_mask);
            carry = (short) (subtraction_result < 0 ? 1 : 0);
        }
        for (; i >= xOffset && carry > 0; i--) {
            if (x[i] != 0)
                carry = 0;
            x[i] -= 1;
        }

        return carry > 0;
    }

    public short isGreater(byte[] x,short xOffset,short xLength,byte[] y ,short yOffset,short yLength)
    {
        // Beware: this part is not tested
        while(xLength>yLength) {
            if(x[xOffset++]!=0x00) {
                return 1; // x is greater
            }
            xLength--;
        }
        while(yLength>xLength) {
            if(y[yOffset++]!=0x00) {
                return -1; // y is greater
            }
            yLength--;
        }
        // Beware: this part is not tested END
        for(short i = 0; i < xLength; i++) {
            if (x[xOffset] != y[yOffset]) {
                short srcShort = (short)(x[xOffset]&(short)0xFF);
                short dstShort = (short)(y[yOffset]&(short)0xFF);
                return ( ((srcShort > dstShort) ? (byte)1 : (byte)-1));
            }
            xOffset++;
            yOffset++;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private void modular_division_by_2(byte[] input, short inOffset, short inLength, byte[] modulus, short modulusOffset, short modulusLength) {
        short carry = 0;
        short digit_mask = 0xff;
        short digit_first_bit_mask = 0x80;
        short lastIndex = (short) (inOffset + inLength - 1);

        short i = inOffset;
        if ((byte) (input[lastIndex] & 0x01) != 0) {
            if (add(input, inOffset, inLength, modulus, modulusOffset,
                    modulusLength)) {
                carry = digit_first_bit_mask;
            }
        }

        for (; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
            if ((input[i] & 0x01) == 0) {
                input[i] = (byte) (((input[i] & digit_mask) >> 1) | carry);
                carry = 0;
            } else {
                input[i] = (byte) (((input[i] & digit_mask) >> 1) | carry);
                carry = digit_first_bit_mask;
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testModMultiply() {
        Random r = new Random(12345L);
        for(int iiii=0;iiii<10;iiii++) {
            BigInteger modulus = BigInteger.probablePrime(NUM_BITS, r);
            System.out.println(" M = " + modulus);
            byte[] modulusBytes = normalize(modulus.toByteArray());
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(modulusBytes, (short)0, tempBuffer, Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_MODULUS, Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS);

            mRsaPublicKekForSquare.setModulus(modulusBytes, (short)0, (short)modulusBytes.length);
            mRsaPublicKekForSquare.setExponent(new byte[] {0x02}, (short)0, (short)1);

            for(int iii=0;iii<1000;iii++) {
                BigInteger x = new BigInteger(NUM_BITS, r).mod(modulus);
                System.out.println(" x = " + x);
                BigInteger y = new BigInteger(NUM_BITS, r).mod(modulus);
                System.out.println(" y = " + y);
                BigInteger accResult;
                {
                    byte[] xBytes = normalize(x.toByteArray());
                    byte[] yBytes = normalize(y.toByteArray());
                    byte[] accResultBytes = modMultiply(xBytes, (short)0, (short)xBytes.length, yBytes, (short)0, (short)yBytes.length, Configuration.TEMP_OFFSET_RESULT);
                    accResult = new BigInteger(1, accResultBytes);
                }
                System.out.println(" Qr = " + accResult);
                BigInteger realResult = x.multiply(y).mod(modulus);
                System.out.println(" Rr = " + realResult);
                Assert.assertEquals(realResult, accResult);
            }
        }
    }

    private byte[] normalize(byte[] xBytes) {
        if(xBytes.length<Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS) {
            xBytes = ArrayUtils.addAll(new byte[Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS-xBytes.length], xBytes);
        }
        if(xBytes.length>Configuration.LENGTH_MODULUS) {
            Assert.assertEquals(xBytes[0], 0x00);
            xBytes=Arrays.copyOfRange(xBytes, 1, xBytes.length);
        }
        return xBytes;
    }
}
```

What was (IMHO) wrong:

1. The `isGreater()` method -- although it is possible to use subtraction to compare numbers, it is much easier (and faster) to compare corresponding bytes starting from the most significant one and stop on the first mismatch. (In the subtraction case you would need to complete the subtraction and return the sign of the final result -- your original code ends on first "mismatch".)
2. `x+y` overflow -- you should have kept the modulus subtraction for the addition overflow case (i.e. when `add()` returns true) in your last edit.
3. Offsets into `eempromTempBuffer` -- on two places you used `yOffset` and should have used `0` (commented out with a "WRONG OFFSET").
4. Casting `Configuration.LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS-1` to `byte` is not a good idea for larger values of modulus length

Some (random) comments:

- the test uses already mentioned [jcardsim](https://jcardsim.org/) to work
- the code assumes that lengths of `x` and `y` are both `LENGTH_MODULUS` (as well as `LENGTH_RSAOBJECT_MODULUS` being equal to `LENGTH_MODULUS`)
- it is not a good idea to have `eempromTempBuffer` in a non-volatile memory
- your code is VERY similar to [this code](https://github.com/mobilesec/secure-channel-srp6a-applet/blob/master/src/at/fhooe/usmile/securechannel/sc_srp_6a/UsmileKeyAgreement.java) which is interesting
- an interesting read regarding this topic is [here](https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/395143113437/dissertacao.pdf) (section 4.2.3).

Good luck!

Disclaimer: I am not a crypto expert nor mathematician so please do validate my thoughts

Comment: @Drago Edited the answer as I forgot to mention the overflow of `x+y` needs to be handled. And added the link mentioned in my previous comment.